# SQL Server - CTE inside a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
WITH months(dt) AS 
   (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS dt 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(month, -1, dt)
    FROM months)
SELECT 
top (datediff(month, '2020-01-01', DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)) + 1) 
YEAR(months.dt) yr, MONTH(months.dt) mnth
FROM months
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

What I need is that the last Select result is a CTE expression so I can use it on other select.

I have tried this:

```
WITH months(dt) AS 
   (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS dt 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(month, -1, dt)
    FROM months),
    cte2 as (
SELECT 
top (datediff(month, '2020-01-01', DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)) + 1) 
YEAR(months.dt) yr, MONTH(months.dt) mnth
FROM months
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
)
```

But I get an error, Im doing something wrong for sure.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You need to add the final `SELECT` over `cte2`. For example:

```
WITH 
months (dt) AS 
   (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS dt 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(month, -1, dt)
    FROM months),
cte2 as (
    SELECT 
    top (datediff(month, '2020-01-01', 
           DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)) + 1) 
    YEAR(months.dt) yr, MONTH(months.dt) mnth
    FROM months
)
SELECT * from cte2
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

This way you can chain two, three, four, etc CTEs one after the other. Any CTE can JOIN, use, or combine any of the CTEs defined previously.